# MySQL Alter Table Add Field Before or After a field already present

Tags: php, mysql

I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE `".$table_prefix."posts_to_bookmark` 
            ADD `ping_status` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL BEFORE `onlywire_status`";
```

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 221, accepted):

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE `" . $table_prefix . "posts_to_bookmark` 
          ADD COLUMN `ping_status` INT(1) NOT NULL 
          AFTER `<TABLE COLUMN BEFORE THIS COLUMN>`";
```

I believe you need to have `ADD COLUMN` and use `AFTER`, not `BEFORE`.

In case you want to place column at the beginning of a table, use the `FIRST` statement:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE `" . $table_prefix . "posts_to_bookmark`
          ADD COLUMN `ping_status` INT(1) NOT NULL 
          FIRST";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Yep, AFTER or FIRST, not BEFORE. +1

Comment: For use BEFORE has sense  to  understand "why I want put this field there".

When I target the first place of a "serie" of fields in my row, I just add  " # AKA BEFORE `fieldname`

Comment: use [FIRST | AFTER col_name] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html