# PDO Alter table adding multiple columns SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I want to add some columns in to existing database table after the last column i want to add these.. the scritp will be avalaible for everyone so not sure what will be the last column.

```
$DB_Column = array (
        'About_Me' => "About", 
        'Avatar' => "Avatar",
        'Clan_Tag' => "Clan",
        'Month' => "Month",
        'Day' => "Day",
        'Year' => "Year",
        'Website' => "Website",
        'Website_Link' => "Link",
        'Website_Link1' => "Link1",
        'Email_Address' => "Email"
    );

$Database->exec('ALTER TABLE '.$DB_Table.' 

            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['About_Me'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Avatar'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Clan_Tag'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Month'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Day'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Year'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Website'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Website_Link'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Website_Link1'].' VARCHAR(255),
            ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Email_Address'].' VARCHAR(255) 
    ');
```

Getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ",": syntax error' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webstats\Functions.php:30 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webstats\Functions.php(30): PDO->exec('ALTER TABLE
>   RCO...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Webstats\Index.php(3):
>   require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webstats\Functions.php on line 30

Answer (score 1):

The [ALTER TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) allows only one column.

Comment: Oh really? not at all we can add multiple columns!

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- How can you be so sure?Did you check the document of sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot add more than one column using alter table command.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

[image]

Comment: Sir check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541312/alter-table-add-multiple-columns-after-column1

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- Did you checked that it is a MYSQL not SQLITE! In MySql it is allowed but not in Sqlite:)

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- No it is not possible in Sqlite! :( you need to have repeated calls to ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Well, repeating alter table is not bad but what about AFTER i want automatic last column to be selected and new column to be added after last one! can it be>?

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. I would suggest you may better ask a new question if that is a different issue :)

Comment: Still getting error is this syntax correct?
$Database->exec('ALTER TABLE '.$DB_Table.' ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['About_Me'].' VARCHAR(255)');
 $Database->exec('ALTER TABLE '.$DB_Table.' ADD COLUMN '.$DB_Column['Avatar'].' VARCHAR(255)');

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- Pass only one statement inside exec at a time :)

Comment: Passing one but not working see
$Database->exec('ALTER TABLE '.$DB_Table.' ADD '.$DB_Column['About_Me'].' VARCHAR(255)');

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- Try this:- `$Database->exec('ALTER TABLE '+.$DB_Table.+' ADD '+.$DB_Column['About_Me']. '+ VARCHAR(255)')`

Comment: Syntax error '+.$DB_Column['About_Me'].'+ aslo tried .+' but still

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai:- That is because of the space you need after the .$DB_Column['About_Me']. Please try this:- `$Database->exec('ALTER TABLE '+.$DB_Table.+' ADD '+.$DB_Column['About_Me']. '+ VARCHAR(255)') `