# Adding multiple columns in MySQL with one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to add multiple columns to an existing table in phpMyAdmin, but I keep getting the same error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax ...

I am writing:

```
ALTER TABLE `WeatherCenter`
   ADD COLUMN
      BarometricPressure SMALLINT NOT NULL,
      CloudType VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
      WhenLikelyToRain VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL;
```

I have referred to past posts on StackOverflow, and I am following the experts' recommendation, so why am I getting an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alter table add MULTIPLE columns AFTER column1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541312/alter-table-add-multiple-columns-after-column1)

Answer (score 59):

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name
 ADD COLUMN column_name datatype
```

correct syntax

```
ALTER TABLE `WeatherCenter`
   ADD COLUMN BarometricPressure SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   ADD COLUMN CloudType VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
   ADD COLUMN  WhenLikelyToRain VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL;
```

check [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 13):

You need to specify multiple `ADD COLUMN`

```
ALTER TABLE `WeatherCenter`
      ADD COLUMN  BarometricPressure SMALLINT NOT NULL,
      ADD COLUMN CloudType VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
      ADD COLUMN WhenLikelyToRain VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can alter a table and add multiple columns in one statement by doing it like this.

```
alter table WeatherCenter add column (BarometricPressure SMALLINT NOT NULL, CloudType VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL, WhenLikelyToRain VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
alter table A add first_name varchar(10),last_name varchar(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're adding columns to an existing table I don't think you're meant to declare NOT NULL in the statement. Also, you don't need to use **ADD COLUMN**, you can just use **ADD**.

```
ALTER TABLE WeatherCentre
   ADD BarometricPressure SMALLINT,
   ADD CloudType VARCHAR(70),
   ADD WhenLikelyToRain VARCHAR(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from [Official MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]
    [partition_options]

alter_specification:
    table_options
  | ADD [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
  | ADD [COLUMN] (col_name column_definition,...)
```

Possible duplicate of [alter table add MULTIPLE columns AFTER column1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541312/alter-table-add-multiple-columns-after-column1)

Answer (score 0):

alter table table_name add (product varchar(20) not null, price int(10))

this is also working fine