# MySQL error 1064 - What is this error for?

Tags: mysql

I want to add this to the existing table in my database, but I get this error!

`ALTER TABLE renting  ADD renting_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,  ADD payment_amount DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL ,  ADD pay_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,  ADD pay_due_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,  ADD debts DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL ;`

What's the error here?

***#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL ,  ADD `pay_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' , ' at line 1***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
ALTER TABLE renting ADD renting_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
ADD payment_amount INT(10) NOT NULL, 
ADD  pay_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
ADD pay_due_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' , 
ADD debts INT(10) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 ALTER TABLE renting  
       ADD COLUMN renting_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
       ADD COLUMN payment_amount DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL,
       ADD COLUMN pay_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
       ADD COLUMN pay_due_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
       ADD COLUMN debts DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL ;
```

check this [Adding multiple columns in MySQL with one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195977/adding-multiple-columns-in-mysql-with-one-statement)

Comment: you can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541312/alter-table-add-multiple-columns-after-column1