# Create columns in table from list

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I create multiple columns in a table from a list?

table name: **teachers**

column names list:

```
first_name
last_name
email
phone
age
birthday
school
district
subject
...
...
...
```

how can I create those columns with `VARCHAR (20)` all **`null`** in my table?

Comment: This looks like **[XY Probem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**. Describe what case do you want to solve. Creating tables on the fly sounds somehow as poor design. Of course it is doable using dynamic SQL. Also storing `age` and `birthday` as string is very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

To `CREATE` a table, one would do:

```
CREATE TABLE pet (first_name VARCHAR(20), last_name VARCHAR(20),
   email VARCHAR(255), phone VARCHAR(20), age INT, birthday DATE, school VARCHAR(100), etc...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used this code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20655740/4357238

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN log VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
ADD COLUMN status INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
ADD COLUMN count SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL
AFTER lastname
```