# Wordpress database query inserting column

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to alter a database in Wordpress and adding new columns to it. Here is the code:

```
function new_columns_users(){

    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "users";

    $sql = "ALTER TABLE $table_name ADD (
        gender varchar(10),
        test varchar(10)
        ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

This doesn't add the new columns in the database. I feel like I tried everything, what is wrong with this query?

Comment: do you execute the query somewhere in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alter table add MULTIPLE columns AFTER column1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541312/alter-table-add-multiple-columns-after-column1)

Comment: yes this gets executed already checked with an error log

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: checked out the other answer but still not sure how to place $charset_collate in the answer they gave.

Comment: You shouldn't need it. That's only really used for creating new tables.